# jQuery template/tmpl how to build dynamic output from json?

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates, jsrender

Trying to build dynamic output from json and using jq/template tmpl display rows/columns.
Somehow i need to iterate thru columns and Rows not sure how.

I do **NOT KNOW** name of json properties, so it needs to be dynamic.

*Finally got an answer* [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9006673/103303)

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
        <li>{Need Loop here?}</li>           
 </script>

var invoice = {
  invoiceItems: [
    { type: 'item', 
      part: '99Designs', description: '99 Designs Logo', 
      price: 450.00, qty: 1 },
    { type: 'service',
      service: 'Web development and testing', 
      price: 25000.00 },
    { type: 'item',
      part: 'LinodeMonthly', description: 'Monthly site hosting', 
      price: 40.00, qty: 12 }
  ]
};

$("#template")
    .tmpl(invoice.invoiceItems)
    .appendTo("#place_holder");
```

Also, is any way to display json property name?
Like:

type > part > description> .....

Here's [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pyccki/G4FxZ/1/)

***Update***:

I start using [Jsrender](http://borismoore.github.io/jsrender/demos/), much faster. I still haven't figure out how to create dynamic templates. Will update if get completed.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-each/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got a help from Friend of mine.

Template

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
{{each(i, invoiceItem) invoiceItems}}
    <li>
    {{each(j, property) $item.getProperties(invoiceItem) }}
       ${invoiceItem[property]} >>
    {{/each}}
    </li>
{{/each}}
</script>
```

Helper function

```
var functionHelpers = {
getProperties: function(invoiceItem) {
    var properties = [];

    for(var key in invoiceItem) {
        properties.push(key);
    }

    return properties;
}
```

};

Here's working example [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GSMRH/2/)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery Templates are no more:

http://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/archive/2011/12/01/goodby-jquery-templates-hello-jsrender.aspx

Comment: Thanx Steve, but i'd like to use jquery tmpl. :(

Comment: From their site: jQuery Templates plugin 

Note: The jQuery team has decided not to take this plugin past beta. It is no longer being actively developed or maintained.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you think you need to loop, jquery.tmpl is doing the looping for you.  You just need to use `${}` to output the data in the markup you want: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GSMRH/1/).

Comment: Problem is that i don't know json Prop names, json will be build dynamically.

Comment: Do you mean you wish to link to a variety of json structures?

Comment: @ Steve, i didn't really want to create 5-20 different templates, i was looking for a way to build on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for : [Angular](http://angularjs.org/).

You get more than just template rendering ( you can also make your templates more dynamic ) but you also get a two way data binding which in most cases is very welcomed.

Comment: Need to check performance against jsRender.
My main issue, that i have a LOT of Data to render :)
Here's some Perf test for jsRender
http://borismoore.github.io/jsrender/test/perf-compare.html